# can an event have activities asssociated with it?

Tags: civievent, civimember

Looking to use CIVICRM as an event scheduler with "activities" associated with an event.  Similar to class scheduling for a day long seminar.

Event Attendees would sign up for 1 or more activities within the event.

Please advise!

Answer (score 3):

CiviCRM lets you create price sets, which can be used to create an event sign-up with all kinds of different selections, such as workshops in different time slots. You'd create a price set field for each time slot, and the field would be set up with as many options as you needed to choose from. There can be a price associated with each different selection, or they can be "free"/zero dollar, or some combination.